# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'xaxis'

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

When trying to create a plot with multiple figures, I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'xaxis'
```

My code is:

```
plt.figure()
n_cols = 6
n_rows = int(len(df.foo.unique()) / n_cols) # 4
fn, axis = plt.subplots(nrows=n_rows, ncols=n_cols, figsize=(30, 25))
for i in range(len(df.foo.unique())):
    sb.scatterplot(x='var1', y='var2', hue='foo', data=df[df.foo == i], ax=axis[i])
```

And `foo` is a variable from value `0` to `23`, so it has `length = 24`.
But it works when I hyperparametrize `nrows` and `ncols` ONLY assigning the following values. By doing the following, I get success:

```
plt.figure()
fn, axis = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=12, figsize=(30, 25))
for i in range(len(df.foo.unique())):
    sb.scatterplot(x='var1', y='var2', hue='foo', data=df[df.foo == i], ax=axis[i])
```

Why is this happening?

A deeper view of the error:

```
File c:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py:46, in _deprecate_positional_args.<locals>.inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     36     warnings.warn(
     37         "Pass the following variable{} as {}keyword arg{}: {}. "
     38         "From version 0.12, the only valid positional argument "
   (...)
     43         FutureWarning
     44     )
     45 kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46 return f(**kwargs)

File c:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py:825, in scatterplot(x, y, hue, style, size, data, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, markers, style_order, x_bins, y_bins, units, estimator, ci, n_boot, alpha, x_jitter, y_jitter, legend, ax, **kwargs)
    822 if not p.has_xy_data:
    823     return ax
--> 825 p._attach(ax)
    827 p.plot(ax, kwargs)
    829 return ax

File c:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_core.py:1134, in VectorPlotter._attach(self, obj, allowed_types, log_scale)
...
-> 1134     axis = getattr(ax, f"{var}axis")
   1135     seed_data = self.plot_data[var]
   1136     if var_type == "categorical":

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'xaxis'
```

Comment: First, you should remove `plt.figure()` as it creates an empty figure which is not used because `plt.subplots(...)` creates a new figure (filled with subplots).   Further, `plt.subplots()` returns a figure and some `ax`s, often called `fig, axs = plt.subplots(....)`.  By default, if there are multiple rows and multiple columns, `axs` will be a 2D array. It will be a 1D array when either one is `1`. It will be a single `ax` when both are `1`.  You can use `axs = np.ravel(axs)` to always convert it to a 1D array.